# How do I return an IQueryable from Linq to SQL query when the dbContext is with a 'using' block?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I've been coding with 'using' blocks but I am wondering if I can return an IQueryable from the following without the object being disposed before I access it.

```
public IQueryable<Contact> GetContacts(string clientID)
{
    using (dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext())
    {
        var contacts = from _contacts in db.Contacts
                        where _contacts.ClientID == clientID
                        orderby _contacts.LastName ascending
                        select _contacts;

        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Do I simply remove the 'using' block and let .Net manage the objects, or can I get Linq to run the query early and return the populated object.

Comment: note that it's not really necessary to explicitly dispose the datacontext. good question though anyway.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet - er, yes it is. Any disposable object should be assumed to **require** disposal, and should be handled appropriately, IMO. It can hold an open connection, for example...

Comment: @Marc: I'm just going on what I've read on several blogs, and also pretty much all the examples by ScottGu and the Linq team. The official microsoft position, as far as I can gather, is that you can dispose if it makes you feel better, but it really isn't neccessary. See http://leedumond.com/blog/about-disposing-the-datacontext/ as an example for some discussion of dispose and the defered execution problem described in this question.

Comment: Scott Guthrie: *"The Datacontext object actually doesn't hold open any connections to the database - so you don't have to explictly dispose of it.  Instead, it retrieves new connections from the connection pool only when it needs them, and then returns them as soon as it is done."* You can't really get it on any higher authority than that.

Comment: For anyone looking, here is an updated link for the article @fearofawhackplanet posted: https://web.archive.org/web/20130702164240/http://leedumond.com/blog/about-disposing-the-datacontext/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't expect to further compose the data (at the db-server), then:

```
return contacts.ToList().AsQueryable();
```

although in that case I'd prefer to return `IEnumerable<Contact>` or `IList<Contact>` to make the non-composable nature obvious. With the `AsQueryable` approach, it'll still *be* composable, but it'll compose via LINQ-to-Objects (so *after* it has fetched the records from the database).

If you *do* expect to further compose it, then you should pass the data-context (or, if possible, an upstream `IQueryable<something>`) *into* the method, and let the caller handle the lifetime:

```
public IQueryable<Contact> GetContacts(dbDataContext db, string clientID)
{
    return from _contacts in db.Contacts
           where _contacts.ClientID == clientID
           orderby _contacts.LastName ascending
           select _contacts;
}
```

Comment: @IckleMonkey - it is the *concrete* type that matters most there, but one obvious advantage of `IList<T>` is that it will expose `.Count` etc (and an indexer), making access more convenient. But regardless of `IList<T>` vs `IEnumerable<T>`, it still *is* a `List<T>`, so memory usage is independent. Or for a more concise answer: use `IList<T>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the context object a member instance of your class? If you can you'll defer the call to run the query until you actually touch the enumerator underlying the IQueryable instance you're returning. It depends on what you want to do. Do you need to return IQueryable from this method, or can you make do with IEnumerable ?

Comment: I think I will go with the IEnumerable, if I use the member instance method, then I may run into the same problem if my class is used as a 'using' block, and I want access to the returned data outside of this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

The contact object instance in IQueryable result set will retain the reference of datacontext used within the using block and will work in the client code much as expected. You will be able to perform deferred SQL operations on the resultant IQueryable instance and do other IQueryable operationas normally.

Comment: When I try, I get 'DataContext accessed after Dispose'.

Answer (score -2):

you could do something like this

```
public IQueryable<Contact> GetContacts(string clientID)
{
    IQueryable contacts;
    using (dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext())
    {
        contacts = from _contacts in db.Contacts
                        where _contacts.ClientID == clientID
                        orderby _contacts.LastName ascending
                        select _contacts;


    }

    return contacts;
}
```

Comment: That won't help - deferred execution of LINQ queries means that the db-context is still disposed long before `GetEnumerator()` is called on the underlying query. So no workee.